# OpenCV - altering the filter2D function

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

In order to convolve a kernel with an image, I am using:

```
 output = cv2.filter2D(image,-1,kernel)
```

This is returning the convolution image that i'm looking for, however I need to trim the height and width both by 2. For example, it is currently returning `output.shape = (157, 298)` and I need it to return `(155,296)` .
I cannot alter the image or the kernel.

Is there a way to perhaps begin at `image[1,1]` (instead of `[0,0]`) and end at `[-1,-1]` in order to trim 2 from both axes?

Comment: You don't have to "alter" the image, you can just slice it. Either before or after, which may have subtly different effects at the edge: `output = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, kernel)[1:-1, 1:-1]` or  `output = cv2.filter2D(image,[1:-1, 1:-1], -1, kernel)`

Comment: Very nice, than you askewchan!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to "alter" the image, you can just slice it. Either before or after, which may have subtly different effects at the edge:

```
output = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, kernel)[1:-1, 1:-1]
```

or

```
output = cv2.filter2D(image[1:-1, 1:-1], -1, kernel)
```